# Custom URL protocol - prevent page reload

Tags: angular

When using custom URL protocol handlers within my angular2 application (with router) a click on the link causes a page reload - at least in Firefox.

```
    <a href="tel:0123456789">call me</a> <br>
    <a href="myuriprotocol:foobar">launch custom application</a>
```

Is there a possibility to prevent that page reload? Using `target="_blank"` isn't a real option as it opens empty browser tabs when used with custom URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So easy... just use iframe

```
<a target="customUrlContainer" href="myuriprotocol:foobar">launch custom application</a>
<iframe name="customUrlContainer" style="display:none"></iframe>
```